# Can the Azure pipeline runtime parameter value be saved and used as a default for the next run?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline with a couple of runtime parameters:

`Primary env` and `Secondary env`:

[image]

Is there a way that I can save the values for those parameters from the previous run and use them as "default" values for those parameters the next time somebody (manually) runs the pipeline?

For example:

1. First run - the default values of the parameters are used - `dev` and `qa`
2. Next run, the defaults are Primary = qa; Secondary = dev and runs the pipeline
3. In the next run, those values are preset as Primary = qa; Secondary = dev again as those were the last ones used
   ...

I guess there are a couple of challenges I am trying to address above:

1. Where I can store the previously supplied parameters? (I am curious if there is a way to store that information within Azure DevOps itself and not on a separate platform such as AWS DynamoDB which adds complexity)
2. How to dynamically set the parameters reading from the saved location?

Comment: How about storing the parameters in a `variable group`? Once someone runs another build, in case the values are empty take the parameters passed in the current run otherwise get them from the `variable group`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, using a variable group to store the parameters could work. In my case, I can remove the runtime parameters and just use the variable group.

Comment: Seems to me like anti-pattern, you are introducing coupling between different runs of the pipeline. Variable groups are way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @FFFffff. In my case, I need to store the previously used parameters so those parameters need to be swapped the next time the pipeline is run. That is the reason why I need to store them. 

In my case, that coupling is necessary, otherwise, I would probably need a more complicated solution such as storing them to a block storage such as DynamoDB table and retrieving them at pipeline run time.